# How to handle a iframe using puppeteer API

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web-scraping, puppeteer

i am try to interact with a iframe on a page, but the iframe has no name, or URL

```
    const frame = await page.frames().find(frame => frame.url() === 'src' )
    console.log(frame);
```

i cant deal with it bacause the name is dynamic, is there any other way to deal with i frames or is this a dead end ?

Comment: If it doesn't have an URL what do you have inside?

Comment: it has a url its src cause from the dom i had src = 'somewierdurl' then when i tried frame.url() with the given url i got undefined

Comment: it might help if you post iframe html ... with its parent